# Source folder "src" does not exist - have you run forge create yet?

Tags: trigger.io

Just downloaded version 3.3.0 for windows today. I installed python and trying to get started with my first app with forge create but I am getting the following in the error log:

```
2012-04-28 18:03:28,285 [   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.0
2012-04-28 18:03:28,288 [  DEBUG] Forge build tools version: 3.3.0
2012-04-28 18:03:28,288 [  DEBUG] main: {"server": "https://trigger.io/api/"}
2012-04-28 18:03:28,299 [  DEBUG] GET https://trigger.io/api/version_check/3/3/0/
2012-04-28 18:03:29,661 [  DEBUG] checking API response for success or error
2012-04-28 18:03:29,661 [   INFO] Update result: you already have the latest tools
2012-04-28 18:03:44,101 [  DEBUG] GET https://trigger.io/api/auth/loggedin
2012-04-28 18:03:44,279 [  DEBUG] checking API response for success or error
2012-04-28 18:03:44,279 [  DEBUG] already authenticated via cookie - continuing
2012-04-28 18:03:44,279 [   INFO] Registering new app "helloworld" with trigger.io...
2012-04-28 18:03:44,279 [  DEBUG] POST https://trigger.io/api/app/
2012-04-28 18:03:56,368 [  DEBUG] checking API response for success or error
2012-04-28 18:03:56,368 [   INFO] Fetching initial project template
2012-04-28 18:03:56,368 [  DEBUG] already authenticated - continuing
2012-04-28 18:03:56,368 [  DEBUG] GET https://trigger.io/api/app/xxx/initial_files/
2012-04-28 18:03:56,579 [  DEBUG] unzip is available, using it
2012-04-28 18:03:56,782 [  DEBUG] unzip output
2012-04-28 18:03:56,782 [  DEBUG] Can't execute /c/Program Files/Common Files/Symbian/tools/unzip.pl.

2012-04-28 18:03:56,782 [  DEBUG] Extracted initial project template
2012-04-28 18:03:56,782 [  DEBUG] Removed downloaded file ".\initial.zip"
2012-04-28 18:03:56,782 [   INFO] Building app for the first time...
2012-04-28 18:03:56,782 [  ERROR] Source folder "src" does not exist - have you run forge create yet?
```

Is it suppose to look for unzip within Symbian folder?

Not sure how to fix this, any help would be appreciated ...

Thanks,
EE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From these lines in the output, it looks like a different version of 'unzip' is being used from what our tools expect:

```
2012-04-28 18:03:56,579 [  DEBUG] unzip is available, using it
2012-04-28 18:03:56,782 [  DEBUG] unzip output
2012-04-28 18:03:56,782 [  DEBUG] Can't execute /c/Program Files/Common Files/Symbian/tools/unzip.pl.
```

This is causing the basic template app not be unzipped (creating the src directory) hence the error.

Could you try removing '/c/Program Files/Common Files/Symbian/tools/unzip.pl' from the PATH and retrying 'forge create'